# how to maintain list item selected color untill another item is not clicked

Tags: listitem, android

i have set values in my list item like

```
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                mListData,
                R.layout.listrow,
                new String[] { "text", "img" },
                new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.img } );
        mLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
        mLV.setAdapter(adapter);
        mLV.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        mLV.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickListener);
```

and my ListItemClickListner is like

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

           System.gc();

    //  int id = mActivity.getResources().getIdentifier(mViews.get(arg2), "drawable", mActivity.getPackageName());
        mView = mViews.get(arg2);
        String str=mTitles.get(arg2);
        Log.i("title", "tit"+str);
```

i am working with android tablet and i am not able to keep selected list item with diff color any know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use custom list adapter extending BaseAdapter and there in getView() set the color of your selected item.